# Assistance with Keras for a noise detection script

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm currently trying to learn more about Deep learning/CNN's/Keras through what I thought would be a quite simple project of just training a CNN to detect a single specific sound. It's been a lot more of a headache than I expected.

I'm currently reading through [this](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-build-efficient-audio-data-pipelines-with-tensorflow-2-0-b3133474c3c1) ignoring the second section about gpu usage, the first part definitely seems like exactly what I'm needing. But when I go to run the script, (my script is pretty much totally lifted from the section in the link above that says "Putting the pieces together, you may end up with something like this:"), it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'file_path'
```

I can't find anything in the pandas documentation about a DataFrame.file_path function. So I'm confused as to what that part of the code is attempting to do.

My CSV file contains two columns, one with the paths and then a second column denoting the file paths as either positive or negative.

Sidenote: I'm also aware that this entire guide just may not be the thing I'm looking for. I'm having a very hard time finding any material that is useful for the specific project I'm trying to do and if anyone has any links that would be better I'd be very appreciative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement `df.file_path` denotes that you want access the file_path column in your dataframe table. It seams that you dataframe object does not contain this column. With `df.head()` you can check if you dataframe object contains the needed fields.

Comment: How do i apply those names to the columns?

Comment: can you write the names that are in your dataframe